# Gatsby project not developing because of connection error with Contentful

Tags: environment-variables, gatsby, contentful, gatsby-source-contentful

I opened an old Gatsby project on a new computer to try and complete, but when I tried to set up my development, I ran into this issue:

```
 ERROR 

Problems with gatsby-source-contentful plugin options:
spaceId: undefined - "spaceId" is required
accessToken: undefined - "accessToken" is required
host (default value): "cdn.contentful.com"
environment (default value): "master"
downloadLocal (default value): false
localeFilter (default value): [Function]
forceFullSync (default value): false
pageLimit (default value): 100
useNameForId (default value): true

not finished onPreInit - 0.030s
```

I did some research and saw this [post](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19392) which said they could run the development server but not the Gastby build. I updated my Contentful API key, my .env doc, and made sure the master environment was checked off but I'm still having this issue. Does anyone know what to do?

Here's my [Github repo](https://github.com/kentonscott/My-Portfolio).

Answer (score 1):

On your gatsby-config.js file, you oughta load the env vars
if your defined under the `.env` file the following snippit should work so your spaceID and accessToken aren't undefined.
At the begining of your `gatsby-config.js` add:

```
require("dotenv").config()
```

You can reference this
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the environment variables. Follow these steps:

- Add the following snippet in your `gatsby-config.js`:

  ```
  require("dotenv").config({
     path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
  })
  ```

  `dotenv` comes as a dependency of Gatsby so you don't need to install anything extra.

  Once the snippet is in your `gatsby-config.js`, Gatsby will take your `.env.development` and `.env.production` when running `gatsby develop` and `gatsby build` respectively. Note that is the default behavior, you can customize the target environment file by changing the `NODE_ENV` variable or by setting a `path` in the snippet above

  `NODE_ENV` is equal to `development` and `production`, that's why Gatsby takes each file in different commands.
- Place your environment variables in both `.env.development` and `.env.production` files:

  ```
  CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN=yourAccessToken
  CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID=yourSpaceId
  ```
- Target the environment variables while using the `gatsby-source-contentful`:

  ```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    },
  ```

Comment: Knowing that `dotenv` comes as a dependency of Gatsby therefore no need to install anything extra is critical info Thanks!

Comment: I added that snippet to gatsby-config file but it's still giving an error that it failed to find the .env file. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Besides adding the snippet above, have you added the two environment files (`.env.development` and `.env.production`) to the root of the project with the variables in it? If so, clean the cache by running `gatsby clean`

Comment: Yeah I've added the two files to the root with the variables and clean the cached. I tried running `npm run develop` and got an error that said:

`Error: Failed to find .env file at default paths: [./.env,./.env.js,./.env.json]
    at getEnvFile `

Comment: It's odd. Are they called with the dot at the beginning? Can you share your project structure?